# Can I move common install conditions to a shared WiX Installer project

Tags: wix

I have multiple WiX installer projects in my solution. And all of the installers in the main wxs file under the Product element have the same list of launch conditions, such as privileges, OS version on the target machine, whether NET48 framework is installed or not, etc.

```
<Condition Message="You need to be an administrator to install this product.">
  Privileged
</Condition>

<Condition Message='This product is designed to be installed on Windows 7 or higher Windows Operating System'>
  <![CDATA[VersionNT64 >= 601]]>
</Condition>

<PropertyRef Id='WIXNETFX4RELEASEINSTALLED'/>
<Condition Message='This setup requires the .NET Framework 4.8 to be installed.'>
  <![CDATA[Installed OR (WIXNETFX4RELEASEINSTALLED >= "#528040")]]>
</Condition>
```

So I was wondering if it is possible to have these conditions moved into a shared common project in my solution that I can refer to that project from all my installer projects and inject the conditions from that shared place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only sharing those Launch Conditions then consider using an include file. The conditions will be compiled separately for each project, rather than once, but then you can include them easily without needing to create a shared wixlib.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- LaunchConditions.wxi -->
<Include>
  <Condition Message="You need to be an administrator to install this product.">
    Privileged
  </Condition>

  <Condition Message='This product is designed to be installed on Windows 7 or higher Windows Operating System'>
    <![CDATA[VersionNT64 >= 601]]>
  </Condition>

  <PropertyRef Id='WIXNETFX4RELEASEINSTALLED'/>
  <Condition Message='This setup requires the .NET Framework 4.8 to be installed.'>
    <![CDATA[Installed OR (WIXNETFX4RELEASEINSTALLED >= "#528040")]]>
  </Condition>
</Include>
```

then in each project include it with

```
<?include LaunchConditions.wxi?>
```

Comment: Prefer @Christopher Painter's answer vs. using Include files.

Answer (score 1):

WiX doesn't have a ConditionRef element.  It's a shame cause it probably should.  However fragements are consumed atomically so if you put them in with something else like a Property you could ref the property and get it all together.

I don't know how clean you want your Condition table but another concept is just put all your conditions in one fragement and share them with all your projects.  Then for each condition you an enabling property.  This way the condition only evaluates if the property is set.

Here's something I wrote 16 years ago....  I'd be happy to assist if you want to do something like this.

http://blog.iswix.com/2006/07/short-comings-of-launchconditions.html

Comment: I agree. Is there a feature request open for `ConditionRef`? Seems like something we've discussed and I was surprised this didn't seem solved in v4.